# Scrape a page in R using rvest or RCurl or httr

Tags: rvest, rcurl, httr

I would like to extract the table in the below page

https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/spot-market-price

I have tried rvest and RCurl but in both the cases, the page which gets downloaded is different from what I see in the browser. I am assuming there is some form of redirection which I am unable to detect or follow

Any help would be appreciated

PS:  Not interested in phantomjs

This is what I have tried till now:

**1. HTTR**

```
base_url <- "https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/spot-market-price"
ua       <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
library(httr)
library(XML)
doc <- POST(base_url,user_agent(ua),set_cookies(`_ga` = "GA1.2.543290785.1505100652",`_gid`="GA1.2.1409943545.1505881384",`_gat`="1"))
doc <- htmlParse(doc)
poptable<-readHTMLTable(doc,which=7)
```

Result:  No Data Found!!!!

**2. RCurl**

```
library(RCurl)
curl <- getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(curl = curl,
           ssl.verifypeer = FALSE,
           useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
           timeout = 60,
           followlocation = TRUE,
           cookiejar = "./cookies",
           cookiefile = "./cookies")
newDoc = getURL("https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/spot-market-price", curl=curl)
newDoc <- htmlParse(newDoc)
poptable<-readHTMLTable(newDoc,which=7)
```

Result:  No Data Found!!!!

Also I would be interested to know how to get the excel file (see the small excel icon)

Comment: Is there a reason you explicitly exclude PhantomJS as a solution? In some cases it is simply not possible to scrape data without sth like PhantomJS, RSelenium or similar. Without looking into it it is maybe not possible to solve your question

Comment: @TomS it is a system requirement within our environment which does not allow phantomJS.  It is possible using rvest.  I will post the answer once I have completed the code at my end.  I am close....

Comment: But you are aware that in contrast to e.g. RSelenium PhantomJS doesn't require any kind of installation right? I don't have admin rights on my work machine as well, but it works. However - if you're close to a solution using only rvest (or e.g. httr) I'm happy to read and learn, as I substantially lack of knowledge in that regard :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(V8)

  ctx <- v8()
  pg <- read_html("https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/spot-market-price")
  html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//script[contains(., 'Data')]")[[1]] %>% 
    html_text() %>% stri_unescape_unicode() %>% stri_replace_all_fixed('\\\\', '')%>% 
    ctx$eval() -> ignore_the_blank_return_value
  data <- ctx$get("vSMP")$Data[,c("Symbol","TodaysSpotPrice","Unit")]
```

Enjoy!!!

Comment: really cool! Just started with scraping and encountered already some issues with Java I have to solve without e.g. RSelenium. Never came across the V8 package, though, but results look really good. Thanks!